# chart.js Multiple barchart in time scale won't display all

Tags: javascript, chart.js, bar-chart

Using Chart.js, i want to compare 2 datasets in a timescale. So i send data for each day, but here is my output

[image: Barchart example]

As you can see, for the very first and the very last data, i'm not able to see all my barchart. Very first will show the second dataset and very last will show the first dataset.

## EDIT

Here is a [WORKING CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OzPgqW)

```
var options = {
    legend: {
        position: 'bottom'
    },
    hover: {
        mode: 'point',
        intersect: false
    },
    tooltips: {
        mode: 'x',
        intersect: false,
        callbacks: {
            title: function (tooltip, data) {
                return;
            },
            label: function (tooltip, data) {
                return ;
            },
            footer: function (tooltip, data) {
                return;
            }
        }
    },
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            id: 'timescale',
            type: 'time',
            unit: 'day',
            unitStepSize: 1,
            time: {
                displayFormats: {
                    'millisecond': 'DD MMMM YYYY HH:mm',
                    'second': 'mm:ss',
                    'minute': 'HH:mm',
                    'hour': 'HH:mm',
                    'day': 'DD MMM',
                    'week': 'DD MMM',
                    'month': 'DD MMMM',
                    'quarter': '[Q]Q - YYYY',
                    'year': 'YYYY',
                }
            },
            display: true,
            position: 'bottom',
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: "Heure",
            }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            id: 'consumption',
            type: 'linear',
            position: 'left',
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            },
            scaleLabel: {
                display: true,
                labelString: "Consommation",
            }
        }]
    }
}

var graph = new Chart(element, {
  type : 'bar',
  data : {
    labels : [],
    datasets : [{
      label: 'datasets1',
      type: 'bar',
      backgroundColor: Chart.helpers.color('#0000FF').alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
      borderColor: '#0000FF',
      unite: null,
      yAxisID: 'consumption',
      data: [{x: '2017-10-26T22:00:00.000Z', y:73.16},{x: '2017-11-27T22:00:00.000Z', y:36.16}]
    },{
      label: 'datasets2',
      type: 'bar',
      backgroundColor: Chart.helpers.color('#FF0000').alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
      borderColor: '#FF0000',
      unite: null,
      yAxisID: 'consumption',
      data: [{x: '2017-10-26T22:00:00.000Z', y:87.16},{x: '2017-11-27T22:00:00.000Z', y:24.16}]
    }],
  },
  options : options         
});
```

Comment: Please add the required code to reproduce this chart

Comment: Yes, i updated the post with the codepen

Comment: Hi! Did you found a solution? I have this same problem.

Answer (score 3):

I've faced the same problem and fixed it by adding `offset: true` option to `scales.xAxes`

Here is your code with one new option https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yQqrVz?editors=0010 - now all bars are visible.

And here is my example https://jsfiddle.net/0bnmc4eg/3/

I found the solution in this conversation https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/4545